# Operator-Overloading in C++ (Copy-Constructor & Destructor)

Tags: c++

When I run the following code in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
        string name;
        Test();
        Test(string pname);
        ~Test();
        Test operator+(Test right);
};

Test Test::operator+(Test right)
{
    Test neo_name;
    neo_name.name = name + "-" + right.name;
    return neo_name;
}

Test::Test()
{

}

Test::Test(string pname)
{
    name = pname;
}

Test::~Test()
{
    cout << "~ " << name << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Test D1("a");
    Test D2("b");

    Test D3;
    D3 = D1 + D2;

    return 0;
}
```

I notice that the `+` operator overload method destroys the "a-b" (neo_name) and "b" (right) objects.

```
(1) ~ a-b
(2) ~ b
(3) ~ a-b
(4) ~ b
(5) ~ a
```

Does anyone know how to destroy each object once?

At the end, I expect an output like:

```
(3) ~ a-b
(4) ~ b
(5) ~ a
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can avoid copying the `b` object by taking a `const&` argument (which you should be doing anyway on any structs bigger than a few words). The `a-b` copy will probably be avoided by copy-elision once you turn optimizations on, though I don't think there's a way to guarantee this.

Comment: *I know I should use the copy constructor* -- It is the *compiler* that is utilizing the copy constructor, not you.  That's why you are seeing the copies made.  Instead of printing out `~` along with some text, also print out the value of `this`.  You will see the object being destroyed is not one that you explicitly created.

Comment: And make it `Test D3 = D1 + D2;` to give copy elision a chance. [With all the aforementioned changes](https://godbolt.org/z/TKPqzchhz), you would get the outcome you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few places you can clean up.

Change to this:

```
    Test operator+(const Test & right);
```

Your current implementation requires an unnecessary copy.

Next, when calling your operator+ method:

```
Test D3 = D1 + D2;
```

There's a basic rule that you should almost always initialize when you instantiate. Think about what has to happen.

If you do this:

```
Test D3;
D3 = D1 + D2;
```

Then you're going to construct a default D3 and then in the very next line, you call your operator+ and then copy over D3. But if you do it all on one line, the compiler can be smarter, quite a bit smarter, actually.

Try those changes and see if you're happier.